# Rewriting output of a field in node.tpl

Tags: 7, entities, theming

One way is to use `$node->field_myfield[LANG][0][value]="value"` that needs another line for getting field's language using `field_language()`.

Is there an easier and cleaner way?

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) function. Have a look at [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).